# How to expand condition on \IfEqCase before evaluation?

Tags: programming, strings, xstring

I'm trying to do a simple task (as in the MWE below). When a given text is given (a filename) it outputs a given color.

To work as I intended, `\IfEqCase` should only evaluate the file extension, as presented in the commented lines. Unfortunately, it seems that `\IfEqCase` breaks when I try to add other commands as parameters.

Can you give a help on this?

Best Regards

```
\documentclass{article}

% General settings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Output encoding
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}


\newcommand{\selColor}[1]{%
        \IfEqCase{#1}{%
%       \IfEqCase{\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{\StrPosition{#1}{.}}}{%
        {Snip00.tex}{black}%
        {Snip00.doc}{red}%
%       {tex}{black}%
%       {doc}{red}% 
    }[\PackageError{colorErr}{Undefined color option: #1}{}]%
}

\begin{document}

    Start document here 

    \selColor{Snip00.tex}
    \selColor{Snip00.doc}

    End the document

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\fullexpandargs\IfEqCase{..}` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xstring` commands aren't expandable, so they can't be easily passed as arguments to other commands. Instead, the package allows you to use a trailing optional argument to which the result of the macro is saved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\selColor}[1]{%
  \StrPosition{#1}{.}[\tempa]%
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{\tempa}[\tempb]%
  \IfEqCase{\tempb}{%
    {tex}{black}%
    {doc}{red}% 
  }[\PackageError{colorErr}{Undefined color option: #1}{}]%
}

\begin{document}

Start document here

\selColor{Snip00.tex}
\selColor{Snip00.doc}

End the document

\end{document}
```

This prints:

> [image]

without the error message.

---

An alternative approach with `expl3` that doesn't require saving the commands in intermediate steps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\selColor{m}
  { \__acombo_sel_color:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \__acombo_sel_color:n #1
  {
    \str_case:fnF { \__acombo_extension:n {#1} }
      {
        { tex } { black }
        { doc } { red }
      }
      { \PackageError{colorErr}{Undefined~color~option:~#1}{} }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { f }
\cs_new:Npn \__acombo_extension:n #1
  { \__acombo_extension:w #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__acombo_extension:w #1 . #2 \q_stop {#2}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Start document here

\selColor{Snip00.tex}
\selColor{Snip00.doc}

End the document

\end{document}
```

Here I used a command `\__acombo_extension:n` which will exclude everything until the first `.`, then passed it to `\str_case:fnF` which will try to match that with each extension you give. If it doesn't find a match the error is raised.

---

For both approaches (`xstring` and `expl3`) the behaviour is undefined when there are multiple `.` or no `.` in the argument to `\SelColor`. Here's a version which:

- If there's no dot, the string used is the whole argument (*i.e.:* `\selColor{tex}` is the same as `\selColor{Snip00.tex}`);
- If there's more than one dot, the extension used is the one which starts with the last dot (*i.e.:* `\selColor{Snip00.hello.doc}` is the same as `\selColor{Snip00.doc}`);

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\selColor{m}
  { \__acombo_sel_color:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \__acombo_sel_color:n #1
  {
    \str_case:fnF { \__acombo_extension:n {#1} }
      {
        { tex } { black }
        { doc } { red }
      }
      { \PackageError{colorErr}{Undefined~color~option:~#1}{} }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { f }
\cs_new:Npn \__acombo_extension:n #1
  { \__acombo_extension:w #1 . \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__acombo_extension:w #1 . #2 \q_stop
{
  \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2}
    {#1}
    { \__acombo_extension:w #2 \q_stop }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

Start document here

\selColor{Snip00.tex}
\selColor{Snip00.doc}
\selColor{tex}
\selColor{Snip00.hello.doc}

End the document

\end{document}
```

which prints:

> [image]